# jQuery adding / chaining elements to one variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-chaining, jquery-append

how can I turn this into something faster:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) 
{ 
    rcItemsLi.eq(index++).append('<div class="rc-item-content clear hidden"><p class="rc-item-context">' + val[0] + '</p>' + val[1] + '</div>'); 
}); 
rcItemsContent = $('.rc-item-content');
```

in this example, I first append the elements to where I want, then I use .rc-item-content selector to "find" all the elements and store them in rcItemsContent variable.

for example:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) 
{ 
    rcItemsContent.add($('<div class="rc-item-content clear hidden"><p class="rc-item-context">' + val[0] + '</p>' + val[1] + '</div>').appendTo(rcItemsLi.eq(index++))); 
});
```

in this example, what I'm trying to achieve (which of course I don't), is to add / chain the element in the variable and append it to where I want at the same time.

Comment: Don't append inside of a loop.

Comment: @BenM why can't you append in a loop?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, you can, but it's advised againt > http://stage.learn.jquery.com/performance/append-outside-loop/

Comment: @BenM is there a way to append one element from collection to one element in other collection, for example I got collection of 3 divs, and collection of 3 paragraph, I want to paragraph 1 will be appended to div 1, paragraph 2 to div 2 and paragraph 3 to div 3, without using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.add` creates a new collection.

```
rcItemsContent = rcItemsContent.add(...
```

Comment: `rcItemsContent = rcItemsContent.add($('<div class="rc-item-content clear hidden"><p class="rc-item-context">' + val[0] + '</p>' + val[1] + '</div>').appendTo(rcItemsLi.eq(index++)));` still not working, what am I missing?

Comment: @Ron does it add anything?  You may need `.end()` after the `.appendTo` call

Comment: I think that the problem is how I declared the variable rcItemsContent - I declared it this way: `var rcItemsContent`. maybe I need to declare it as jquery variable / object / w.e and I dont know how

Comment: @Ron you can create an empty jQuery collection with `var rcItemsContent = $([])`

Comment: worked. I didnt need the `.end()` since `.appendTo()` keep the original selector. Thank you very much.